# Creating a numpy array with repetitive pattern

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to create an array of size 6*n, such that for every batch of 6 cells in the array I will have the following integer values:

```
a = [n-2, n-1,n,n,n+1,n+1,n+2,n+3]
```

The banal way that I can think of is using this routine:

```
a = []
for i in xrange(n):
    np.append(a,[n-2, n-1,n,n,n+1,n+1,n+2,n+3])
```

But is there a smarter-faster way of doing it?

Comment: Your example is still broken, which makes it harder to understand exactly what you want. If you want a single list you could use `a.extend([n-2, n-1,n,n,n+1,n+1,n+2,n+3])`, or if you want nested lists you could use `a.append([n-2, n-1,n,n,n+1,n+1,n+2,n+3])`

Comment: Are you sure about `6`? The length of your pattern is `8`. Your code gives an array with length `8*n`. And do you mean to have `i` in your loop or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
>>> n = 6
>>> arr = np.array([n-2, n-1, n, n, n+1, n+1, n+2, n+3])
>>> np.tile(arr, n)
array([4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8,
       9, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7,
       8, 9])
# Reshape to get the desired output
>>> np.tile(arr, n).reshape(n, arr.size)
array([[4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: I don't think the `reshape` is needed. OP's example gives a 1d `(8*n,)` shaped array.